# In FinancialData what is the difference between FractionalChange and Change?

Tags: curated-data, finance

In [`FinancialData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FinancialData.html?q=FinancialData&lang=en) there are two similarly named properties one can request for a given stock symbol: `Change` and `FractionalChange`. What is the difference between these two properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"FractionalChange"` is the change, represented as a fraction of the previous price:

```
{change = FinancialData["AAPL", "Change"],
 fracchange = FinancialData["AAPL", "FractionalChange"],
 today = Last[Last[FinancialData["AAPL", "Close", {{2013, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0}}]]],
 yesterday = Last[Last[FinancialData["AAPL", "Close", {{2013, 6, 28, 0, 0, 0}}]]]}

(* ==> {12.69, 0.032, 409.22, 396.53} *)

{change, today-yesterday}

(* ==> {12.69, 12.69} *)

{fracchange, (today-yesterday)/yesterday}

(* ==> {0.032, 0.0320026} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the closing price of Apple on the last friday (i.e., 4 days ago):

```
p1 = FinancialData["AAPL", {DatePlus[Date[], -4]}, "Value"]
```

> {396.53}

Now consider the yesterday's closing price  (i.e., 1 day ago):

```
p2 = FinancialData["AAPL", {DatePlus[Date[], -1]}, "Value"]
```

> {409.22}

The **difference** between these two prices can be calculated:

```
p2 - p1
```

> {12.69}

This is exactly the dollar ammount, given by the `"Change"`:

```
FinancialData["AAPL", "Change"]
```

> {12.69}

Now consider the **percent change** of Apple from friday until monday, given by $\dfrac{P_{t}-P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}$:

```
(p2 - p1)/p1
```

> {0.0320026}

This value is what is given by `"FractionalChange"`:

```
FinancialData["AAPL", "FractionalChange"]
```

> {0.032}